# Find if :-char is between [ and ]

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a solution to find if a :-char is enclosed by [ and ] or not.

I have a sort of syntax which enables to define keys with corresponding values in a template. The syntax is exploded by :-char to identify the keys, but a :-char should also be valid if it's within the brackets. Basically my sample/case is like:

`:key1[value]:key2[this:value should work too]`.

I'm looking for a way to find if :-char is within the brackets. I've started writing out a procedure to figure this out, but somewhere during the writing an electronic pulse in my mind said 'regex.. regex'. But I'm quite unfamiliar with them. Could someone help me out?

P.s. if you're downvoting the question, at least tell me why you think its a bad question. In my opinion its a correct question I'm asking assistance for.

Comment: So you just need to check if `:` is within `[]` or there is some another task behind that?

Comment: "but somewhere during the writing an electronic pulse in my mind said 'regex.. regex'." --- now you have 2 problems

Comment: I need to find `:`, and that's the only task. I'm using it for a multi language purpose in a template parsing script. The keys are language-codes, the values between `[` and `]` are the values for a specific language.

Comment: what do you want to match...a key,,value..what

Comment: Do you want to do anything with the keys => values or just find the `:` ?

Comment: I'm just after the `:`, Because they can be within the brackets, or outside to specify a new key.

Comment: @Ben Fransen: so - I've provided a trivial regex to find if `:` is within brackets as you asked )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm gonna show you the general way to parse this: [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eP7kY5)

`:(key\d)+\[([^\]]+)\]`

What you need to do is match everything between `[` and `]` so instead of using `.*` you must tell the Regular Expression that you want to MATCH EVERYTHING that is not `]` so... `[^\]]`

You can see the demo for more explanation.

Comment: Great answer, even better explanation. I can throw some of my other validation-code away as well because this demo does exactly what I'm after! +1 Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('~\[[^\]]*:~', $str)
```

this will return `1` if there is a `:` char within brackets. The regex assumes the brackets are always paired.

Answer (score 1):

To find whether :-char is within [] it is enough to put in your regexp following:

```
preg_match('/\[:-char\]/', $string);
```

This will match all ":-char" wrapped with [ ]. Please note that [ ] chars are part of regexp pattern and hence should be escaped.
If you want to find all ":-char", but see whether it has [ ] or not, then you go for

```
preg_match('/(\[)?:-char(\])?/', $string, $var);
```

Then result of everything in ( ) will be captured into `$var`. And from the structure of it you can judge whether it was wrapped with [ ] or not

For better understanding how regular expressions work i would suggest standard PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php

Comment: Also a great answer doing the trick. Too bad I can only accept one answer. +1 , thanks!

Comment: @BenFransen Just before posting to SO, better dig a bit into documentation ;) This is simple beginner level question and could be solved without asking here, and then you wouldn't get down voted. Just check the official docs. They are easy to understand. Try their examples.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Well, regex to me are many times pretty confusing, that's why I've asked the question. To some the question may have been too easy/general, to me it was an unclear subject I asked assistance for. Sometimes I provide answers to very (to me) easy question, but the person asking might find it difficult, or is just unsure how to approach the 'problem' :)